# Issue with CGImageCreateWithImageInRect when cropping UIImage

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimage, crop, cgimage

I know there is a bunch of threads about this, but still i can't find an answer for my situation.

I'm fetching UIImage from `PHAsset` object, and than crop the Image as follow.

[image]

Using this code :

```
 let fImage = preview.image!.fixOrientation()
        let newSize = CGSizeMake(img!.width * (cropFrame.width / previewFrame.width),img!.height * ( cropFrame.height / previewFrame.height))
        let pX = (fabs((previewFrame.width - cropFrame.width)) / previewFrame.width) * img!.width
        let py = (fabs((previewFrame.height - cropFrame.height)) / previewFrame.width) * img!.width

        var newRect = CGRect()
        newRect.size = newSize
        newRect.origin = CGPointMake(pX, py)

        let imageRef: CGImageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(fImage.CGImage, newRect)!
        let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: fImage.scale, orientation: preview.image!.imageOrientation )
```

Where `fixOrienation` is

```
 func fixOrientation() -> UIImage {

        // No-op if the orientation is already correct
        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up ) {
            return self;
        }

        // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
        // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
        var transform: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Down || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.DownMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI))
        }

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Left || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
        }

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Right || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,  CGFloat(-M_PI_2));
        }

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.DownMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0)
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
        }

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored || self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored ) {
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        }

        // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
        // calculated above.
        let ctx: CGContextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(self.size.width), Int(self.size.height),
            CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
            CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
            CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage).rawValue)!;

        CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform)

        if ( self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Left ||
            self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored ||
            self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Right ||
            self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored ) {
                CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage)
        } else {
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage)
        }

        // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context and return it
        return UIImage(CGImage: CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx)!)
    }
```

Yet the outcome is

[image]

**Any suggestions?** **THANKS!**

Comment: clearly, your `newRect.origin` isn't correct, so I would like into how you calculate `pX` and `pY`

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier Tho if the (0,0) is at the top left(as usual to UIKit), im calculating the proportional distance((max x - origin x)/ maxX) , than multiple with the imgX should give us the correct origin point on the real image?

Comment: well, from a quick glance, you are using width and height instead of the origin and also, you are using width when calculating pY

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier oh wow, sorry for that(second part). Can you please elaborate about the first part? (Using width and height instead of origin)

Comment: it is correct to use width and height of your `cropFrame` if you are calculating size, which you did. but when calculating origin, you will not get a correct result. use it's origin instead.

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier  sounds great, I'll check it as soon as i come back to my computer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104003/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-konrad-bajtyngier).